# Convert output into a table

Tags: java, format, output, text-files

I am using this method to print some data from a text file, and try to output it into a table format.
The first parameter simply requests a word that must be in the middle column, and the `colSize` should set the column width.

```
public String printTable(String midWord, int colSize) {
    String col1 = "";
    String col2 = midWord;
    String col3 = "";

    System.out.printf( "%-15s %15s %n", col1, midWord, col3);
    //System.out.format ( "%-15s %15s %n", col1, midWord, col3);

    return null;
}
```

I have tried using both `printf` and `System.out.format` but they both seem to be doing the same thing so I am not sure about them.

Can anyone explain what I am missing in this method.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the file and the code that is parsing the file ?

Comment: What's the problem? And where is `colSize` being used?

Comment: @LaneSurface i wasn't sure how to use it... ☹️

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear: Are you trying to read a (text-)file, knowing that the lines are composed of 3 columns, the second (and therefore the middle one) is supossed to be known?
With the following snippet, it's possible to read a file:

1. all lines in one time and print them line for line
2. using a scanner and print one word after another

   ```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.nio.file.Files;
   import java.nio.file.Paths;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.stream.Stream;

   public class TestClass {
      private static final String fileName = "I:/myFile.txt";    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<String> lines;
        Scanner scanner;
        try {
            lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName));
            lines.toArray(String[]::new);
            // read all lines
            List<String> readAllLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));
            // print each of the lines
            readAllLines.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));

            // print a word each time
            File file = new File(fileName);
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
               System.out.println(scanner.next());
            }

       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }  
     }
   }
   ```

If you have a problem puting the read lines (with 3 "columns" each??), let me know this, I'll try to help.

Comment: well, i am trying to get some data from a text file and then print it into the console. but i wanted to format it so that it is in three columns, with the middle column being specifically the one word should show in the middle

Comment: here http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet you find all what you need to format your output: